# Volume charge density of a single point

Tags: charge, density, point-particles

**The original problem:**

[image]

---

I read [this one](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/46249/delta-dirac-charge-density-question), but there's something that is still unclear, even after going through all their answers and comments.

Why doesn't the expression use the 3-dimensional Dirac Delta function? That is, shouldn't the expression be: $$\rho (\overrightarrow r ) = q \delta^3 (\overrightarrow r  - \overrightarrow r')$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's just a notational issue.  $\delta(\vec{r} - \vec{r}')$ does refer to the 3D delta function, as you can tell because it has vectors inside of it.  It's probably more clear to write it as $\delta^3(\vec{r} - \vec{r}')$ but it means the same thing.

Comment: Wait, so are there only 1-D and 3-D Dirac Delta function definitions? Because I was going to say: What if those vectors are only in the xy-plane? Therefore, the expression would be ambiguous.

Comment: @whatwhatwhat You can have delta functions in any number of dimensions - the dimension of the delta function is the same as the dimension of the vector inside of it.